# How to change hardcoded database paths in a Lotus Approach Database

Tags: lotus-approach

One of our Lotus Approach files (file extension .apr) has hardcoded paths to additional underlying database files (file extension .dbf).  We've moved the Approach database and all the underlying files to a new network drive, so these paths need to be updated.  You can see the old paths by opening the File menu and selecting "Approach File Properties", under the "Databases" heading.

How can you change these paths?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this same problem and finally figured it out.....

Open the ODBC administrator: c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe

Find the DSN currently in use and remove it.

Now, run Approach and open your file.  It will automatically prompt you to redefine the DSN.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the .apr file into the directory the databases are in, launch Approach and let it re-sync the paths, save, and then you can move the .apr file back to where it was.